# Change default template for new java class in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I create a new .java class in IntelliJ or any other idea besides blueJ it just starts off with

```
public Class app {

}
```

Is there a way to set it to open with something different like an MVC Architecture template like this?

```
public class App{

    private int x;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class App
     */
    public App()
    {
 
    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
     * @return    the sum of x and y
     */
    public int sampleMethod(int y)
    {
        // put your code here
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit Java Class template under **Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates > Files > Class**

[image]

Here is the [documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html) describing that functionality

Comment: Thank you, this worked amazingly. I would upvote your answer, but I don't have enough rep yet.